# Excel VBA formula with double quotes in the formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use an Excel macro to insert this into a cell:

`=REPLACE(B2,1,SEARCH(",",B2)+1,"")&" "&LEFT(B2,SEARCH(",",B2)-1)`

I have tried surrounding each double quote with double quotes:

`Range("A2").Formula = "=REPLACE(B2,1,SEARCH(""",""",B2)+1,"""")&"" ""&LEFT(B2,SEARCH(""",""",B2)-1)"`

I have also tried replacing the double quotes with CHR(34).  It always seems to think that I am ending the formula after the second quote.

Comment: Try `= "=REPLACE(B2,1,SEARCH("","",B2)+1,"""")&"" ""&LEFT(B2,SEARCH("","",B2)-1)"`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this approach is easier to manage without losing count of how many quotes you've added around the existing quotes:

```vb
Range("A2").Formula = _
  Replace("=REPLACE(B2,1,SEARCH(',',B2)+1,'') & ' ' & LEFT(B2,SEARCH(',',B2)-1)", _
          "'","""")
```

Comment: Great suggestion.  I do that in Python, too.

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 rules in such situations.

- Within quote escaping double quotation mark : Two double quotation marks directly.
- String concatenation sign always with leading and trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

I need some data or information to verify your problem and so, It will be easier to help you with some info about what is the kind of data in B2.

So without a clear message, I can't help you.

Comment: Thanks, Jean.   Tim's answer was it!  Appreciate it.